# Why do I find it so hard to share my work?

Tags: web-development

I've done some application out there, coding is not the problem. But when it comes to deploying / communicating / sharing with colleagues and friends, I'm like stuck. I feel I'm going to be humiliated because there are bugs, and people will not use it ...

I'm sure I'm not the only one in this situation. I can't describe it well but ... Here's an example.

You made a todo list manager web application, you use it for some time now. You think it's nice, it does the work - for you, but you just don't got the strength to email your friend or your work buddies, because they will look at you differently, like "he's the one with ambition that did a not so good application" ...

Comment: Thanks for all the answers... It helped me, but I'm not there yet. Obviously there's not "right" answer.. I thaught the article pointed out by Doc was the a great answer, so I'll mark it. Thanks all !

Comment: when you do something you usually piss off the ones that wanted to make the same thing, the ones that wanted to make the opposite thing and a big chunk of the ones that didn't want to make anything. So i think your fears are understandable and very common. Try to look for a environment where people are truly happy when you do something (important or not). It's not easy but i think it is the only solution. And above all don't be jealous or judgmental about other's work: if you can be positive towards others you will be rewarded

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making a software just for your own is a little bit different from making software for others. Read Joel Spolsky's great article

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/DevelopmentAbstraction.html

and perhaps you find a better understanding why this is as it is.

Comment: great artcile Doc! It describes well the work of a scrum master. It makes me thing that I should start considering users of my app as testers, designers ... because feedback is a way of saying : "this doesn't work for me. take a look at it". But it's not a 100% scrum master because he brings problem, not solution you have, as a developer, to *just* code.

Comment: @Marcel as long as the bugs don't completely ruin the experience, and most people won't notice them, you've got it exactly right. Your users are the best testers you will ever have.

Answer (score 10):

I'm sure there's some better quote somewhere but

> If you're afraid to fail you'll never succeed

All software has bugs ... period.  If you ship you will ship bugs and yeah maybe you'll get a a few negative reviews here and there.  But so long as you act on the bugs customers find and have a reasonable ship cadence customers will forgive mistakes.

Also if you don't ship you won't find half the bugs that are actually there.

Comment: additionally, anyone has programmed something complex knows there are going to be bugs and was in your shoes at some point. Bugs (within reason) won't make others think less of you.

Answer (score 2):

You've hit the nail on the head. There are so many alternatives to software that people can afford to be picky. Don't take it personally if they go for a big  brand-name.

One of the things you can do is try to test more, ask your friends to help test, or simply acquire feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Feedback from your friends can make your software only better because they can give you their view on your application so that you can improve it. If you fear criticism:

> Do not seek praise, seek criticism. To improve, you need it. - Anon
>
> To avoid criticism, do nothing, say
>   nothing, and be nothing. - Elbert Hubbard
>
> Statue has never been set up in
>   honor of a critic. - Jean Sibelius